# Como Criar um evento no Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics-api

Como criar um evento para saber quantos cliques teve no vídeo do meu site que está dentro de um iframe?

Por exemplo:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-_J9rlkd1Yc?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Onde insiro o código ga?

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse link, pode ser que te ajude. http://tableless.com.br/monitoramento-de-eventos-com-google-analytics/

Comment: Tem um tutorial que fiz pelo Tag Manager.
Só dar uma olhada https://pablocabral.com.br/google-tag-manager/evento-no-google-analytics/